# aes256-wrap Error 'ERR_CRYPTO_INVALID_IV' But AES-KW Does Not Require An Initialization Vector?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, aes, subtlecrypto

[MDN mentions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/wrapKey#aes-kw) that:

> AES-KW does not require an initialization vector (iv)

But when I try and encrypt my content encryption key (CEK) using the key encryption key (KEK) like below Node.js Crypto `createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv[, options])` throws an error `ERR_CRYPTO_INVALID_IV`. Does anyone know if AES-KW requires an `iv`? The [Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) Key Wrap Algorithm](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3394) RFC does not mention "initialization vector" at all.

```
let cipherCEK = createCipheriv('aes256-wrap', keyEncryptionKey, null);
let encryptedCEK = cipher.update(contentEncryptionKey);
encryptedCEK += cipher.final(); //buffer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you say that RFC 3394 doesn't mention an IV. It's covered in section 2.2.3, and is used for data integrity (i.e. to make sure that the key was decrypted correctly). The default value recommended is A6A6A6A6A6A6A6A6. I haven't tested with `createCipheriv`, but I would recommend passing this value.

I expect that MDN says it doesn't "require" an IV because there is a default one that Microsoft automatically uses, so you don't need to pass it. I expect Node.js just isn't quite that developer-friendly.

Comment: I did not understand that `initial value` and `initialization vector` were the same thing? Re MDN, it could be that the WebCrypto API (vs Node's Crypto module) defaults to that `A6A6...` IV?

Comment: I expect that WebCrypto does if they say you don't need to pass anything.